# Javascript at end of page runs on Div, how to run again with onkeyup

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that holds text and a URL.  When the page loads a JavaScript at the bottom of the HTML runs to create a URL preview of the URL in the div.  It works when the page loads but I want it to run again anytime the content of the `<textarea>` above that div is changed.  The contents of the textarea repopulate the div fine but the JavaScript to create the URL preview doesn't run against the div once the content of the div updates.  Any thoughts?    Type some text and a URL at the link below to see what I mean.

[Demo here](https://www.1stfeed.com/Link-Preview/testlink.php)

`testlink.php`:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTextarea").keyup(function(){
        // Getting the current value of textarea
        var currentText = $(this).val();                    
        // Setting the Div content
        $(".myP").text(currentText);
     });
    });
```

```css
    .myP {};
    body>div { border-top: 1px solid #888; padding: 20px; }  
    .output{
        padding: 10px;
        min-height: 50px;
        margin: 20px 0;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
     }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>  

    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
        <textarea id="myTextarea" rows="5" cols="60" placeholder="Type something       here..."></textarea>
    </form>
    <div class="myP"></div>                              
    
    <div class="myP">
    My first text block. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwfojQKh-1E End.
     </div>

     <div class="myP">
       My 
       <a href="http://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/28/opinion/sunday/even-roger-federer-gets-old.html">
    Second text</a> block
     </div>
    
       <script async 
          src="guteurls.js"
          nocache="1"
          selector=".myP">
     </script>
    
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are calling the guteurl.js script only once, on pageload.  If you want it to run every time a key is pressed, you need to call the script from inside your keyup function.   From initial research, it looks like the documentation for that library is behind a paywall, so I can't help you with implementation.

Comment: Thats what I want to do, run it every time at keyup.  But I dont know the coding for how to do that.  I've been looking but find nothing.  The script for the guteurl.js requires 'selector' and 'nocache' options as well.  Documentation and examples are at https://guteurls.de/

Comment: Looking at what I think is the GuteUrls website documentation.  try adding document.guteUrls.execute() inside your keyup function.

Comment: thanks @ncox85.  adding this has no affect.  Here is the code block for the keyup function.
`code`
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#myTextarea").keyup(function(){
     // Getting the current value of textarea
    
     var currentText = $(this).val();                    
     // Setting the Div content
     $(".myP").text(currentText);
    
     document.guteUrls.execute();

      });
     });
     </script>

Comment: Ok, one last idea.  Make your script a function, then call it as a callback in your reference to GuteUrl script.  try Example 5 on this page. https://guteurls.de/examples.php .

Comment: That may be closer to a solution.  I need help turning this script into a function.  I don't know how to add the 'selector=' and 'nocache=' tags or variables to the function.

      <script async  
          src="https://guteurls.de/guteurls.js" 
          callback-a="document.changePostTitleLink"
          selector=".myP > span"></script>

Answer (score -1):

Please explain your Question in more detail

- What do you want when bottom side script will run?

  Now you are applying class selector on three different div and these text is 
   going to be change with text area.

  https://jsfiddle.net/cj6zgjhw/1/

Comment: I need this script to run as a called function on all divs with class "myP" when keyup action occurs in textarea with the id="myTextarea".   I am not sure how to convert this script to a function properly.    <script async 
      src="guteurls.js"
      nocache="1"
      selector=".myP">
 </script>

Comment: Basically, you type some text and a url into the textarea, and on every 'keyup' it runs the script to check for url and if found the script function guteurls.js with two parameters will be called to change that url into a link preview.